# Significance of has_unchecked_assembly_data due to a persisted computed column after changing compatibility level?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-clr

This database has a persisted computed column, which is computed by calling a .NET function. When changing compatibility from MSSQL 2005 to 2012, I was presented with error 10334, which looks more like a warning: it's telling me that it had to mark one of the tables as has_unchecked_assembly_data.

What it doesn't tell me is what to do about this. Should I leave it as is? Should I force the column to be recomputed somehow? How?

[image]

[The documentation for alter assembly unchecked data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186711.aspx) lists several causes for this, and I think #1 is the only one that applies to this database. It also doesn't explain how to unmark such columns.

Comment: `DBCC CHECKTABLE` or `DBCC CHECKTABLE` will set the `has_unchecked_assembly_data` to zero according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx.

Comment: @DanGuzman It did, thank you! I did a fair bit of googling but couldn't find this. I'll accept if you post as an answer.

Comment: @romkyns Just FYI, the documentation that you linked to for ALTER ASSEMBLY actually does explain this fix: `UNCHECKED DATA:
By default, ALTER ASSEMBLY fails if it must verify the consistency of individual table rows. This option allows postponing the checks until a later time by using DBCC CHECKTABLE.` ;-)

Comment: @srutzky hah! You're right. I did not recognize that as an SQL command, nor did it occur to me to google that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Execute `DBCC CHECKTABLE` or `DBCC CHECKDB` to set the has_unchecked_assembly_data to zero.  This is documented in the [SQL Server Books Online sys.tables reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx).

Comment: I think you have the DBCC listed twice ;-). Also, this fix is documented in the [ALTER ASSEMBLY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186711.aspx) documentation under the `UNCHECKED DATA` option. Just mentioning that for completeness :-).

Comment: @srutzky, thanks for pointing out the typo.  Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

While Upgrading to SQL Server 2017, i needed to run `DBCC CHECKDB` or `DBCC CHECKTABLE` with the `EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS` option to set `has_unchecked_assembly_data` to zero.

References:
[Assemblies - Implementing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/assemblies-implementing?view=sql-server-2017#_managing)
[Performing Logical Consistency Checks on Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#performing-logical-consistency-checks-on-indexes)